# How to check the delayed_job is running or not in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job

Is there any way to check if the `delayed_job` is running or not?

I have a rails app with `delayed_job` deployed on heroku. The DJ is running on `worker` dyno. However, it stopped working yesterday. I checked the `worker`'s status by `heroku ps` and it's `up`.

```
=== worker (Standard-1X): bundle exec rake jobs:work (1)
worker.1: up 2018/03/20 22:06:57 +1100 (~ 19h ago)
```

And I also went to the rails console to check the queue by `Delayed::Job.all` and found there are 112 jobs waiting but not executed.

I also checked the logs, but I didn't find any useful information. The worker log just stopped printing yesterday.

Finally, I restarted the `worker` dyno and it worked again.

```
heroku restart worker.1
```

Does there any way to check why the `delayed_job` was not working in Heroku? Any command in rails console?

Cheers

Comment: Have you ever find out what causes this? We also have workers which I have to restart on a daily basis. Using rails 6.